# Jenkins Job build time duration for sub projects

Tags: jenkins

I have a job A, in which I call jobs B, C, D and E and F, now at the end of completion of A I want to get an email notification with consolidated status of B,C,D,E and F in A' email notification. I am able to get the build result in consolidated email of A. But not able to find a way to get the time duration taken by each job in that email. Can someone suggest?

Answer (score 0):

if you are waiting for the internal jobs ( B,C ,D , E , F)

you should have something like this in your log

```
22:07:53 Waiting for the completion of B
22:21:25 B #3050 completed. Result was SUCCESS
```

and you can get parse the last result of B ( and c,d,e,f) with some groovy script.

Comment: Thanks Mor, but I was able to get the result in a consolodated email, but struggling with the duration.

Comment: Hey, we did it, for getting the status of sub jobs there is an option to block parent and then we can use vars like TRIGGERED_BUILD_RESULT_JOBNAME to get status and for duration we need to do some groovy scripting

Comment: Thanks for sharing